# SSH into ec2 from jenkins and run commands

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, ssh

I am trying to configure my Jenkinsfile so that my master jenkins ssh's into a remote ec2 server and run commands *on the remote server*. So far I added my master jenkins server public key to my remote ec2 server's authorized_keys list and I am able to ssh into my remote server. Relevant parts of my Jenkinsfile:

```
echo "===> about to SSH into the dev environment.."
        sh '''#!/bin/bash
          echo "===> in bash script now"
          ssh -tt ubuntu@xxx.xx.xx.xxx
          ls
          pwd          
          git pull origin master
          rm -rf node_modules
          npm install
          node app.js
        '''
```

I know I was able to ssh into my remote ec2 instance because `ls` prints the contents of the files on my remote server.

However, `pwd` prints out `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/jenkinsfile_master` *which implies i'm still on my master jenkins server*. Furthermore, my `git` and `npm` commands don't run because `git` and `npm` are not installed on my Jenkins master server.

Therefore, my first question is did I really ssh into my remote server? If i did, why does `pwd` print the working directory on my Jenkins server instead of my remote server? And secondly, how can I truly run commands on my remote server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speculating on the behaviours you're experiencing each command is being invoked individually to the command line (which would mean each was run as a different session). If this is the case you would need to chain them all without any additional plugins such as the below example.

```
ssh -tt ubuntu@xxx.xx.xx.xxx && ls && pwd && git pull origin master .....
```

There is a Jenkins plugin named [SSH Steps](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/ssh-steps/) that will allow you to run each command like the below

```
sshCommand remote: remote, command: "ls"
sshCommand remote: remote, command: "pwd"
sshCommand remote: remote, command: "git pull origin master"
```

Alternatively if you do not want to use this plugin, AWS also have a feature named [Run Command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html) that allows you to invoke a command remotely on a server using the AWS CLI/SDK. With this as you're using a `git pull` command you would need to make sure credentials existed on the disk of remote server.